# Is there a way to manipulate NSUserDefaults stored information

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift2

I have stored a dictionary into NSUserDefaults like this:

`standardDefaults.setObject(switchStater, forKey: "startUp")` the `switchStater` object is the dictionary that stores the `rowIndex` and the `Bool` value for each `UISwitch`. I can print out the information that is stored in the `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
let test = standardDefaults.objectForKey("startUp")
        print(test)
```

This is how I confirm the data is stored properly. I put the `.setObject` in the sublass of the `UITableViewController` because the subclass writes the`UISwitch` when they are manipulated. I then call the `.objectForKey` in the `viewDidLoad` of the superclass.

Is there a way to test the `NSUserDefault` stored with a `for init` loop if not how can I test the test so the `UISwitch` is in the position it was left after the user reloads the app?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the stored `Dictionary` from `NSUserDefaults` with `userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("startUp")` then loop through the key/values in the dictionary and set the `UISwitch` appropriately like this:

```
let dictionary = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("startUp")!

for (key, value): (String, AnyObject) in dictionary {
    let switch = value as! UISwitch
    print(key)
    print(switch.on)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch man.  This was the missing link I was looking for.